# Visual Studio Setup Project "sleeps" before actually installing the product

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, installation, setup-project

This seems to be a common behavior for a VS Setup Projects:

1) Created a WPF application.

2) Created Setup Project for the app. Straight forward and all defaults.

3) Built Setup Project and clicked `Install` on it.

Here is what happens next:

1) Setup starts.

2) All preliminary dialogues pass by.

3) Setup says `Click "Next" to start installation`.

4) "Next" button is clicked.

5) Setup says `[my product] is being installed`, "Please wait...", then freezes for 20-40 seconds without visually doing much, as seen by Task Manager/Resource Monitor. Just bloody sleeps!

[Sleeping screenshot](http://s17.postimg.org/9n4rrjsan/screenshot_9.png)

6) It installs my application within a fraction of second, files are actually copying, etc. Progress bar jumps!

The important thing: this "sleeping" can be fixed. SOMEHOW. Example is Araxis Merge Setup, which is characteristically Visual Studio's, and it doesn't sleep, proceeds (with progress bar) straight in.

So, a million dollar question, HOW?

Thanks.

Comment: Of course, an `everything from defaults` test shows the same result, as do demo setups from the Internet.

Comment: Took a closer look with Resource Monitor. On this machine it takes 16 seconds of `sleeping`, and it is messing up with files, CreateFile/CloseFile many-many times, all Program Files or Windows directories.

Comment: `many-many times` here is about 325 K events

Answer (score 0):

Do the install and create a verbose log to see where that wait is. msiexec /i [path to msi file] /l*vx [path to text log file]

Some of the possibilities are:

1. A System Restore point is being taken, that may take a while on some systems. You could try installing the MSI with a command line MSIFASTINSTALL=1 to see if disabling the restore makes a difference:
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408005(v=vs.85).aspx
2. If there are a lot of files already installed that you are updating (because it's an upgrade maybe) there's a lot that goes on in the InstallValidate action to decide what files need updating. The same is true if many of the files being installed have versions on disk that are in use but will be updated - owning processes need to be identified for files-in-use issues.
3. If you include some VC++ merge modules I vaguely recall some long-running things going on in certain versions, related to SxS. The only built-in custom action might be a check for the NET FW if you're using that, but that shouldn't take a long time.

Comment: Thanks! Option 1) was the case